# Rails 3 & Sinatra integration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, rack

I am trying to set up a sinatra app inside my Rails 3 (v3.0.1) application, but having no success. Sinatra gem (v1.1.0) is setup using bundle install.

Here's what i have.

**customer_app.rb** class in lib directory -

```
class CustomerApp < Sinatra::Base

  get "/test" do
    "Hello World"
  end

end
```

my **routes.rb** file contains -

```
CustomerService::Application.routes.draw do

    root :to => CustomerApp

end
```

The URL i am trying is - http://localhost:3000/test

I get this error (on the browser) - **Routing Error. No route matches "/test"**

and this error in the log - **ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/test"):**

Is there anything I am missing??

Also I just noticed, even a simple rack route is not working -

```
root :to => proc { |env| [200, {}, ["Welcome!"]]}
```

Comment: lib directory reloads only when server is restarted. So, if you started your server before you saved changes to customer_app.rb file, it will not hook up. Although, it's just a hint. Can you give a bit more details?

Comment: i was able to get to this problem, but have a new one. would you know how to solve this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191698/sinatra-rails-3-routes-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `root` keyword by default maps only the path `/`.

So you are trying to say, forward any request for `/` to `CustomerApp` which can handle requests for `/test`.

You should change the match filter.

```
CustomerService::Application.routes.draw do
  match "/test" :to => CustomerApp
end
```

Comment: thanks, that worked. Do you know if nameD parameters work with Rails/Sinatra Setup, i m having no luck getting them to work??

Comment: would you know how to solve this issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191698/sinatra-rails-3-routes-issue .thanks