# Sinatra & Rails 3 routes issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I have just setup Sinatra v1.1.0 inside my rails (v3.0.1) app. But I can't invoke any routes that are more than 1 level deep, meaning this works - http://localhost/customer/3,

but this one does not work - http://localhost/customer/3/edit and I get a "Routing Error"

Here's the Sinatra object

```
class CustomerApp < Sinatra::Base

  # this works
  get "/customer/:id" do
    "Hello Customer"
  end

  # this does NOT work
  get "/customer/:id/edit" do
    "Hello Customer"
  end

end
```

This is what I have in my rails routes.rb file -

```
match '/customer/(:string)' => CustomerApp
```

I am guessing I need some magic in the routes file? What could be the problem?

Comment: The routes.rb file has a ton of examples commented out.

Answer (score 3):

In your routes file, you can specify the mapping this way:

```
mount CustomerApp, :at => '/customer'
```

Now, inside your sinatra application, you can specify your routes without the `/customer` part.
Dont't forget to require your sinatra application somewhere (you can do it directly in the route file)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an additional route to match the different URL:

```
match '/customer/(:string)/edit' => CustomerApp
```

Comment: thanks thats totally weird, meaning you need to duplicate the URLs, thats not good.